# Using AngularJS without jQuery, angular.element and $ are both defined, but not equal, so what is "$"?

Tags: angularjs, jqlite

If we load jQuery and then Angular.js, then `angular.element === $` is true and everything is quite clear.

`angular.element("<ul>")` and `$("<ul>")` both create an `ul` element in this case.

However, if we don't load jQuery first, now, `angular.element("<ul>")` works just like jQuery: it creates an `ul` element, and `$` is defined but `$("<ul>")` does not creates an `ul` element but throw an error.  So is `angular.element` exactly jqLite? And what is `$` in this case?

Comment: Yes, `angular.element()` is exactly jqLite

Comment: `$` is only is not defined in Angular, it is a utility of the dev tools which is an alias to `document.querySelector()` and `$$` is an alias to `document.querySelectorAll()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular does not define `$`, but I assume you are seeing it as defined because you are using the browser's dev tools (esp. in Chrome). In Chrome `$` is defined by default as an alias to `document.querySelector()` and `$$` is an alias for `document.querySelectorAll()`. If jQuery is loaded into the page `$` is not defined by Chrome and is instead deferred to jQuery.

In Angular, `angular.element()` is by default jqLite, but if jQuery is loated before angular, it again defers to jQuery.

Comment: Here is exact reference of aliases available in Chrome DevTools : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference. In case someone wants to have a proof :)